# Isotpe filters only on data-filter="*", every other hides everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

My isotope filter, works only on filter link that should display all containers, when every other filter is clicked, all containers are hidden.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMj8v/)

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="isotope-nav">
    <ul class="isotope-filters">
        <li><a class="#" data-filter="*">All posts</a>
        </li>           
        <li><a class="novo isotope-link" href="#" data-filter="novo">Novo</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="uncategorized isotope-link" href="#" data-filter="uncategorized">Uncategorized</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="vesti isotope-link" href="#" data-filter="vesti">Vesti</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- end .isotope-nav -->
<div class="isotope-container">
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container uncategorized ">
        <div class="post-header">   
              <a href="#" class="isotope-link uncategorized">Uncategorized</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end .post-header -->

    </div>
    <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container uncategorized ">
       <div class="post-header">    
             <a href="#" class="isotope-link uncategorized">Uncategorized</a> 
       </div>
       <!-- end .post-header -->

    </div>
    <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container novo novo vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   
              <a href="#" class="isotope-link novo">Novo</a>  <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end .post-header -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container novo novo vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   
         <a href="#" class="isotope-link novo">Novo</a>  <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end .post-header -->
    </div>
     <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
    <!-- end .post-header -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container novo novo vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   
            <a href="#" class="isotope-link novo">Novo</a>  <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end .post-header -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container novo novo vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   
            <a href="#" class="isotope-link novo">Novo</a>  <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end .post-header -->
    </div>
          <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container novo novo vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   
           <a href="#" class="isotope-link novo">Novo</a>  <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end .post-header -->
    </div>
           <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container novo novo vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   
            <a href="#" class="isotope-link novo">Novo</a>  <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end .post-header -->

    </div>
    <!-- end .post-container -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 post-container novo novo vesti ">
        <div class="post-header">   
             <a href="#" class="isotope-link novo">Novo</a>  <a href="#" class="isotope-link vesti">Vesti</a> 
        </div>
            <!-- end .post-header -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .post-container -->
</div>
<!-- end .isotope-container -->
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//isotope
$container = $('.isotope-container');
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.post-container',
    layoutMode : 'masonry'
});

$('.isotope-filters li a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
});
```

**CSS**

```
/**** Isotope filtering ****/
.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the class name using selectors syntax i.e: `.novo` in your `data-filter` attribute but you forgot the `.` and just had `novo`. Same for the others.

Change your `data-filter` values to `.novo`, `.uncategorized` and `.vesti` like this:

```
<div class="isotope-nav">
    <ul class="isotope-filters">
        <li><a class="#" data-filter="*">All posts</a>
        </li>           
        <li><a class="novo isotope-link" href="#" data-filter=".novo">Novo</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="uncategorized isotope-link" href="#" data-filter=".uncategorized">Uncategorized</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="vesti isotope-link" href="#" data-filter=".vesti">Vesti</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DjyF/) - updating the `data-filter` values

---

Comment: i was blind, but now i see :)